# how to getAll on node redis

Tags: javascript, node.js, redis, node-redis

I'm trying get all values from redis using a `hgetall` for return all `'Task_'*` values.

code:

```
var redis = require('redis'),
        client = redis.createClient();

var tasks = [
    {
      "_id" : "t1",
      "creationDate" : "2015-10-02T19:39:37.181Z",
      "device" : "2"
    },{
      "_id" : "t2",
      "creationDate" : "2015-10-02T19:39:37.181Z",
      "device" : "1"
    }
];

tasks.forEach(function(task){
    client.set("task_"+task._id, JSON.stringify(task));
})

client.hgetall("task_", function(e, dt){
    if(e)console.log(e);

    console.log(dt);
})
```

`hgetall` returns `null`

Comment: If you got your solution, mark it as accepted. That how it works!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i found another solution...

```
exports.getAll(calback){
    var arr = [];
    client.keys("task_*", function(e, keys){
      if(e) {console.log(e);}
      client.mget(keys, function(err, values){
        if(err){console.log(err)}
        console.log(values);
        callback(values);
      });
    });
}
```

using "keys" to get all keys, and pass to mget. mget function return all results... is better to process.

Answer (score 1):

`hgetall` is for hashes you have simple keys instead, you could use something like this:

```
client.keys("task_*", function(e, keys){
    if(e)console.log(e);

    keys.forEach(function (key) {
        client.get(key, function (err, value) {
            console.log(value);
        });
    });
});
```

Comment: Glad it works, please consider to accept the answer if it solved your question.

Comment: Just wanted to note that use of the `keys` command is strongly recommended against in production. From [the docs](http://redis.io/commands/keys): "Warning: consider KEYS as a command that should only be used in production environments with extreme care. It may ruin performance when it is executed against large databases. This command is intended for debugging and special operations, such as changing your keyspace layout. Don't use KEYS in your regular application code. If you're looking for a way to find keys in a subset of your keyspace, consider using SCAN or sets."